# Understanding MySql Explain Plan (bad index?)

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a pretty basic query in my system but adding an additional inner join to the query takes the execution time form (0.02 sec to 6.0 sec).  It would seem to me that I'm missing an index on the join column but one does exist.  Below is a `explain plan` of the two queries.  What is going on?

Much faster query....
[image]

Slow query with one additional join (table ='bd')
[image]

Here is the sql...

```
SELECT DISTINCT rsb.id 
FROM   report_session_bill rsb 
       INNER JOIN bill b 
               ON b.id = rsb.bill_id 
       INNER JOIN bill_master bm 
               ON bm.id = b.bill_master_id 
       INNER JOIN meter m 
               ON m.id = b.meter_id 
       -- slow join below... 
       INNER JOIN building bd 
               ON bd.id = m.building_id 
WHERE  rsb.report_session_id = 20693
```

table stats...

- report_session_bill: 1,000 - 10,000 rows, deleted hourly
- bill: 1 million rows
- bill_master: 750k rows
- meter: 10k rows
- building: 7k rows

Comment: Can you show the query as well please?

Comment: @bonCodigo, I've updated to include the sql

Comment: Could you see what would happen if you created an inner query with the filter? `SELECT DISTINCT rsb.id FROM (SELECT * FROM report_session_bill WHERE report_session_id = 20693) rsb ... `

Comment: @njk The slow query runs around 0.3 sec with the sub query.

Comment: @MichaelJ.Lee Is that an improvement?

Comment: @njk yes, absolutely!  Could you provide an answer?